# Docker: Do not try to connect to any registry

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-registry

We ship the container images to the customer in a compressed package, which also contains a python executable which loads the images and starts the services. There is no need to connect to any registry to download or validate the images.

The python script loads all the images through `docker load --input <image>` and starts the `docker services` after all images have been loaded.

In the `dockerd.log` I see services trying to connect `docker.io`:

```
2023-02-28T07:58:59.088+01:00 <MACHINE-ID> dockerd: time="2023-02-28T06:58:59.084275877Z" level=warning msg="Error getting v2 registry: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

2023-02-28T07:58:59.088+01:00 <MACHINE-ID> dockerd: time="2023-02-28T06:58:59.084318502Z" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

2023-02-28T07:58:59.088+01:00 <MACHINE-ID> dockerd: time="2023-02-28T06:58:59.084364323Z" level=error msg="pulling image failed" error="Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" module=node/agent/taskmanager node.id=p5rsdy982kpir355f1hzaeed7 service.id=qxjdbdtxvsx1p2oy7b2y8t3sl task.id=98oveos29urmqgsu3sywtyyo3
```

In the log `qxjdbdtxvsx1p2oy7b2y8t3sl` is the service id of the already created `docker swarm service`, which is why opening connection to `docker.io` does not make sense because the container is already running.

My question is, how do I tell docker to not connect to registry as image is already loaded.

I tried using `--no-resolve-image` option in the `docker service create` command but it does not help.

Answer (score 3):

If they are, literally, running a docker swarm, i.e. with multiple nodes, then it would be advisable to run a registry on the swarm and serve the images from that.

Some notes:

- At deployment (`docker stack deploy`) the manager will check the registry to get the latest sha256 hash for the deployed tag. This has will be appended to the image description sent to all the nodes so that the services state will be stable and consistent on all nodes.
- nodes in a docker swarm need some kind of cleanup over time to clean up stopped tasks, temp volumes for services that have migrated to other nodes. `docker system prune` is the easiest way to do this, but will clear the image cache on each node.
- As from the 1st point - worker nodes do NOT fetch the image from the manager the stack/service was deployed on, but pull it using the image name (and hash). This means the image would need to be pre-cached on each node.

Easier to install an instance of `registry:2`, retag and push images to that so that the swarm has a stable, reliable, location to pull from.

Comment: I understand shipping the registry is a solution, want to find out if there is a way to circumvent issue without it.